# Merge records with duplicate ID and combine different data

Tags: excel, vba

Here is a sample of data from my worksheet. It has been sorted in Column B from smallest to largest to show the duplicate Item Codes (highlighted yellow):

[image: Original Data]

Here is a breakdown of the following columns:

- Column A - ID, every ID is unique
- Column B - Item Code, duplicates appear
- Columns C to E - A range of different data, but if two records have the same Item Code (B), the rest of the data (C to E) will remain the same, as seen above
- Columns F to L - Week numbers (52 in a year hence back to 1 in column K) contains numeric values. Despite multiple records could have the same Item Code (B), columns could contain different numeric values (notice the red marks in the above screenshot)

I want to merge these records, based on finding duplicate Item Codes (B), resulting in storing the first ID value (A), merging columns C to E and combing columns F to L. The screenshot below shows my desired output.

[image: Desired Final Look]

As you can see, the records have been combined and merged. Those with a red mark indicate how these numeric values have been added together to show a new value when there are 2 or more records with the same Item Code but have multiple numeric values in the same column. If there is only one value, it merges with the rest to create one row per Item Code.

I have looked online for a long time and all I could find was using Consolidate and using VBA code to combine these records in a format that didn't lead to this desired output, including using formulas.

Thank you!

Edit: **The above has been answered**. However, below is my original data, I thought the solution for the above question could be easily adjusted and applied to the original data, but I have found no luck with the following code:

```
Sub ConsolidateItemCodes()

   Dim sh As Worksheet, destSh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrH, arrVal, arrfin, arrIt
   Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, dict As Object
   
   Set sh = Sheets("Sample of Original Data") 'use here the sheet you need processing
   Set destSh = sh.Next 'use here the sheet where to return (now in the next sheet)
   
   lastR = sh.Range("F" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   arrH = sh.Range("A1:CO1").Value2           'the headers
   arr = sh.Range("A2:CO" & lastR).Value2  'place the range in an array for faster iteration/processing
   ReDim arrVal(0 To 36) 'redim the array keeping the values
    
   'load the dictionary (ItemCodes as unique keys):
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the dictionary object
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 6)) Then
            For j = 0 To 36: arrVal(j) = arr(i, j + 36): Next j
            dict.Add arr(i, 6), Array(Array(arr(i, 1), arr(i, 2), arr(i, 3), arr(i, 4), arr(i, 5), arr(i, 7), arr(i, 8), arr(i, 9), arr(i, 10), arr(i, 11), arr(i, 12), arr(i, 13), arr(i, 14), arr(i, 15), arr(i, 16), arr(i, 17), arr(i, 18), arr(i, 19), arr(i, 20), arr(i, 21), arr(i, 22), arr(i, 23), arr(i, 24), arr(i, 25), arr(i, 26), arr(i, 27), arr(i, 28), arr(i, 29), arr(i, 30), arr(i, 31), arr(i, 32), arr(i, 33), arr(i, 34), arr(i, 35)), arrVal)
        Else
            arrIt = dict(arr(i, 6))  'a dictionary item can be adaptet directly, EXCEPT arrays...
            For j = 0 To 36
                arrIt(1)(j) = arrIt(1)(j) + arr(i, j + 36)
            Next j
            dict(arr(i, 6)) = arrIt 'place back the updated jagged array
        End If
   Next i
 
   'process dictionary content
   ReDim arrfin(1 To dict.Count + 1, 1 To UBound(arr, 6))
   
   'place the header in the final array:
   For i = 1 To UBound(arrH, 6): arrfin(1, i) = arrH(1, i): Next i
   
   'extract data from dictionary:
   k = 1
   For j = 0 To dict.Count - 1
        k = k + 1
        arrIt = dict.Items()(j)
        arrfin(k, 1) = arrIt(0)(0): arrfin(k, 2) = arrIt(0)(1): arrfin(k, 3) = arrIt(0)(2): arrfin(k, 4) = arrIt(0)(3): arrfin(k, 5) = arrIt(0)(4): arrfin(k, 6) = dict.keys()(j)
        arrfin(k, 7) = arrIt(0)(5): arrfin(k, 8) = arrIt(0)(6): arrfin(k, 9) = arrIt(0)(7): arrfin(k, 10) = arrIt(0)(8): arrfin(k, 11) = arrIt(0)(9): arrfin(k, 12) = arrIt(0)(10): arrfin(k, 13) = arrIt(0)(11): arrfin(k, 14) = arrIt(0)(12): arrfin(k, 15) = arrIt(0)(13): arrfin(k, 16) = arrIt(0)(14): arrfin(k, 17) = arrIt(0)(15): arrfin(k, 18) = arrIt(0)(16): arrfin(k, 19) = arrIt(0)(17): arrfin(k, 20) = arrIt(0)(18): arrfin(k, 21) = arrIt(0)(19): arrfin(k, 22) = arrIt(0)(20): arrfin(k, 23) = arrIt(0)(21): arrfin(k, 24) = arrIt(0)(22): arrfin(k, 25) = arrIt(0)(23): arrfin(k, 26) = arrIt(0)(24): arrfin(k, 27) = arrIt(0)(25): arrfin(k, 28) = arrIt(0)(26): arrfin(k, 29) = arrIt(0)(27): arrfin(k, 30) = arrIt(0)(28): arrfin(k, 31) = arrIt(0)(29): arrfin(k, 32) = arrIt(0)(30): arrfin(k, 33) = arrIt(0)(31): arrfin(k, 34) = arrIt(0)(32): arrfin(k, 35) = arrIt(0)(33)
        For i = 0 To 36: arrfin(k, i + 36) = arrIt(1)(i): Next i
   Next j
   
   'drop the processed array content at once:
   With destSh.Range("A1").Resize(k, UBound(arrfin, 6))
        .Value2 = arrfin
        .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Here is a snippet of my original data. As you can see column A is the same, column B (2) above is actually column F (6), column F (6) is actually column AJ (36) and it ends at column CO (93).

[image: Original Data, not sampled]

And this is my desired output, similar to the above.

[image: Desired Ouput New]

Comment: Your column A got duplicates too. Check  A3 and A7. Anyways, what you want to do is a clear case of Pivot Tables, except for column A, why is the first ID kept and not the others when merging data?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns ah apologies, forget about that, I have updated the screenshot. The first ID does not need to be kept! I know I did say that in my question, that would make Column A's values easier to read but if a solution produced the result in the second screenshot, but with Column A being A1 = "WG193 WG532 WG1033 WG1279" and A2 being - "WG18 WG272 WG1008" this would be fine also.

Comment: OK. Nice explanation of what you need... Something proving that you tried something on your own would also help. I will prepare an answer. It will use arrays and a dictionary. Working mostly in memory it should be very fast, even for larger ranges to be processed.

Comment: Then, please test the code I posted and send some feedback.

Comment: IF you can omit column A, then Pivot Tables is what you need, clearly.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns This is not clear actually, if you think it is please post an answer below.

Comment: Provide a data example everyone can copy/paste and then we can post an aswer using Pivot Tables with that data. Anyways, check [Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It returns (now) in the next sheet against the processed one, but you can set the destination sheet as you want. As I said in my above comment, it uses arrays and a dictionary and should be very fast. Records can be in any order:

```
Sub ConsolidateItemCodes()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, destSh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrH, arrVal, arrfin, arrIt
   Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, dict As Object
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need processing
   Set destSh = sh.Next 'use here the sheet where to return (now in the next sheet)
   
   If sh.FilterMode Then sh.ShowAllData 'to show all data in case of filters...

   lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   arrH = sh.Range("A1:L1").Value2           'the headers
   arr = sh.Range("A2:L" & lastR).Value2  'place the range in an array for faster iteration/processing
   ReDim arrVal(0 To 6) 'redim the array keeping the values
    
   'load the dictionary (ItemCodes as unique keys):
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the dictionary object
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 2)) Then
            For j = 0 To 6: arrVal(j) = arr(i, j + 6): Next j
            dict.Add arr(i, 2), Array(Array(arr(i, 1), arr(i, 3), arr(i, 4), arr(i, 5)), arrVal)
        Else
            arrIt = dict(arr(i, 2))  'a dictionary item can be adaptet directly, EXCEPT arrays...
            For j = 0 To 6
                arrIt(1)(j) = arrIt(1)(j) + arr(i, j + 6)
            Next j
            dict(arr(i, 2)) = arrIt 'place back the updated jagged array
        End If
   Next i
 
   'process dictionary content
   ReDim arrfin(1 To dict.count + 1, 1 To UBound(arr, 2))
   
   'place the header in the final array:
   For i = 1 To UBound(arrH, 2): arrfin(1, i) = arrH(1, i): Next i
   
   'extract data from dictionary:
   k = 1
   For j = 0 To dict.count - 1
        k = k + 1
        arrIt = dict.Items()(j)
        arrfin(k, 1) = arrIt(0)(0): arrfin(k, 2) = dict.keys()(j)
        arrfin(k, 3) = arrIt(0)(1): arrfin(k, 4) = arrIt(0)(2): arrfin(k, 5) = arrIt(0)(3)
        For i = 0 To 6: arrfin(k, i + 6) = arrIt(1)(i): Next i
   Next j
   
   'drop the processed array content at once:
   With destSh.Range("A1").Resize(k, UBound(arrfin, 2))
        .Value2 = arrfin
        .rows(1).Font.Bold = True
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

I tried commenting all code lines, to be easy understood. If something still not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: I have tested it against my sample data and it works perfectly, thank you very much. I will test it against my original data and see if I encounter any issues. But regardless, thank you very much for this, it is excellently written code.

Comment: @EuanM28 Glad I could help. I hope you also learned that if you are not able to help us understanding what you try accomplishing (in details), we cannot help you... I updated the answer after some seconds from posting it. I inserted a code line to `ShowAllData` if the range is filtered. I do not know if what you copied contains it. Then, If that 0 instead of an empty string bothers, the issue can be easily solved...

Comment: Ah yes I copied it before so I have both versions. I have tested it on my original worksheet and it came up with the Run-Time error 13, mismatch and it highlighted the following line of code `arrIt(1)(j) = arrIt(1)(j) + arr(i, j + 6)`. The original file has columns A to CO, A being the ID, F being the Item Code, H to J as the Columns C to E, and from AJ to CO for the week numbers. Trying to figure out why this might be.

Comment: I updated the following lines of code to match my worksheet.
`lastR = sh.Range("F" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`
`arrH = sh.Range("A1:CO1").Value2`           
`arr = sh.Range("A2:CO" & lastR).Value2`

Comment: @EuanM28 Why didn't you show the real sheet structure? Even with dummy data... You should understand the code in order to adapt it. What do you mean by "both versions"? if the "Item Code" is not in B:B column all the logic of loading the dictionary and extract data should be different. Theoretically, if you understand the code, shouldn't be such a big deal... You adapted only the way of the last row calculation and the range to be processed area. But try looking to the way of dictionary loading... I am afraid I do not know how to advice not seeing data. What is it between A:A and F:F columns?

Comment: @EuanM28 Basically there must be **fixt data** As A, C, D, E columns in your question picture, to be used as they are and variable data to be summarized, **but starting from a specific column**. In your question starting from the sixth column. How could I know what you have in your "Real" data? Do you have TeamViewer or AnyDesk installed?

Comment: Please refer to [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as to why I did not show the real sheet structure. As I said, it takes until column AJ to get to the start (week 48), a simple screenshot was not possible. Both versions of your answer. The columns between are just like how column C to E is in the question, repeated values (although different but still repeated)

Comment: I would not be able to show the real data over online as this is confidential. Hence I showed a sample. But to apply what you said, the fixt data format would be as A to E, then G to AI. Column F being the Column B in the question. Column AJ to CO being the values that I wanted to merge/combine.

Comment: @EuanM28 I was not speaking about your real data! Only having **the same structure**. In terms of columns positioning. For the structure you try describing you should load the first "fixed part" in the first array of the jagged one (in the first part of loading the dictionary), immediately after `If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 2)) Then`. Firstly redim `ReDim arrVal(0 To x)`. Instead of 6 you should use the number of columns with variable data - 1. Then the first array (the fixed one) must be load including all missing columns. as `arr(i, 6)`, `arr(i, 7)` and so on. `arrVal` to be loaded from 0 to x

Comment: Okay to send you it via email? I have attempted what you have suggested, but seem to have gotten stuck. No worries if not, I just thought email might be easier.

Comment: @EuanM28 Do it as it looks more convenient. By mail or using a transfer site and let others see it and help. But **if you send it now** I will have some time to look at it. Otherwise, I am leaving my office in about 20 minutes. At the evening I have only a short period to do something for me, then I will leave to the mountains to meat my friends for the new year party...

Comment: @EuanM28 And notify me (here) if you send a mail. I have the mail configured to sent to Spam all mails received from accounts not being in my address book. And I cannot see it.

Comment: No worries, that is it now been sent to you by the email euanmartin28@gmail.com

Comment: I am driving...

Comment: Drive safe! but aye I sent it by email.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub aggregate()

   Const ITEM_CODE = "F" ' Item Code
   Const WK1 = "AJ" ' start of numeric data

   Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, n As Long, c1 As Long, c2 As Long
   Dim c As Long, r As Long, lastrow As Long

   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
   
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ITEM_CODE).End(xlUp).Row
        ' start and end columns
        c1 = .Columns(WK1).Column
        c2 = .UsedRange.Columns.Count + .UsedRange.Column - 1
        
        ' scan up sheet
        For r = lastrow To 3 Step -1
            ' compare with row above
            If .Cells(r, ITEM_CODE) = .Cells(r - 1, ITEM_CODE) Then
                For c = c1 To c2
                    ' aggregate if not blank
                    If Cells(r, c) <> "" Then
                        .Cells(r - 1, c) = .Cells(r - 1, c) + .Cells(r, c)
                    End If
                Next
                '.Rows(r).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                .Rows(r).Delete
                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next
   End With
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   MsgBox n & " rows deleted", vbInformation

End Sub
```